# What permissions are needed in Azure to grant access to a managed identity for calling a custom api

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-managed-identity

I want to assign role Things.Reead.All, created in my app registration to a managed identity.
The app registration SP object id is 8055e1eb-0000-0000-9b77-00000000000
The Role definition looks like this

```
"appRoles": [
        {
            "allowedMemberTypes": [
                "Application"
            ],
            "description": "Allow the application to read all things as itself.",
            "displayName": "Read all things",
            "id": "86a914fa-a862-4962-9975-000000000000",
            "isEnabled": true,
            "lang": null,
            "origin": "Application",
            "value": "Things.Read.All"
        }
```

The only thing known about a system assigned managed identity is its object id, say

aad300-0872-0000-811d-00000000000

and I want to allow it to call the application 8055e1eb-0000-0000-9b77-00000000000 that expects to see the Role in access token.
I know I have to use the following api to do this.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/servicePrincipals/8055e1eb-0000-0000-9b77-00000000000/appRoleAssignedTo
{
  "principalId": "aad300-0872-0000-811d-00000000000",
  "resourceId": "8055e1eb-0000-0000-9b77-00000000000",
  "appRoleId": "86a914fa-a862-4962-9975-000000000000"
}
```

I have wide but controlled access in my tenant. When I acquire a token from

```
az account get-access-token --resource https://graph.microsoft.com
```

and call the above, I get

```
    "code": "Authorization_RequestDenied",
    "message": "Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.",
```

What I need to figure out is the exact privilege that is needed to make this call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you did not answer my comment, I can just give you my own solution which used the service principal to login the azure cli, it works for me.

Please follow the steps below.

1.[Create a new App Registration in azure ad](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-create-service-principal-portal#create-an-azure-active-directory-application), then [get values for signing in](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-create-service-principal-portal#get-tenant-and-app-id-values-for-signing-in) and [create a new application secret](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-create-service-principal-portal#create-a-new-application-secret).

2.Navigate to the `API permissions` of the App, add the *Application permission*(not Delegated permission) `Directory.ReadWrite.All` of `Microsoft Graph`, don't forget to click the `Grant admin consent for xxx` button at last.

**Note:** From the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/serviceprincipal-post-approleassignedto?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#permissions), the `AppRoleAssignment.ReadWrite.All` permission is enough, but per my test, it will not work, not sure if it is a bug, I have decoded the token, the token has the `AppRoleAssignment.ReadWrite.All` permission.

[image]

[image]

3.In azure cli, run the commands below to get the token.

```
az account clear
az login --service-principal --allow-no-subscriptions --username '<application-id>' --password '<application secret>' --tenant '<tenant-id>'
az account get-access-token --resource https://graph.microsoft.com
```

4.I test the token to call the api - [`Grant an appRoleAssignment for a service principal`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/serviceprincipal-post-approleassignedto?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) to grant the app role for the system-assigned identity of my funtion app,it works fine.

[image]

Check it in the portal:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Joy. I was using a service principal with permission 'appRoleAssignedTo' for service principal for obtaining the access token. Unfortunately, I cannot test your solution yet because I cannot add Directory.ReadWrite.All permission to my SP due to limited privileges. Can you describe why this permission is important and I will accept the answer, it is definitely helpful for someone working in this area.

Comment: @Tauqir when you use the service principal to login azure cli, and use the command above to get the token, it uses the client credential flow to get the token, so we need to use the application permission which will take effect in this flow, generally, the permission will be included in the doc.

Comment: @Tauqir But in this case, as I mentioned, per my test the AppRoleAssignment.ReadWrite.All seems not work, the Directory.ReadWrite.All works.